error occurs while building ipa but no error code
I am making an app with flutter
and now I am building ipa but error occurs while building app store ipa
`Encountered error while creating the IPA:
Try distributing the app in Xcode: "open
/Users/ijuyeong/Desktop/Bukpyeong/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive"`
error message above
I did anything that I can but do never worked
plus, when distributing an app, xcode occurs crash
is it related to this problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
